# Saving data from a Flask table to a JSON file without saving deleted rows

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a Flask application that saves a table's data to a JSON file. When I press the "Save" button, the data is not saved correctly. I've tried to edit the code, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

The problem is that the code is saving all the table data, even the rows that have been deleted

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import json
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

data_file = 'table_data.json'

# Load data from previously saved table, if any
if os.path.exists(data_file):
    with open(data_file, 'r') as file:
        table_data = json.load(file)
else:
    table_data = []

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'delete_selected' in request.form:
            selected_rows = request.form.getlist('row_checkbox')
            selected_indexes = [int(idx) for idx in selected_rows]

            # Remove selected rows
            global table_data
            table_data = [row for idx, row in enumerate(table_data) if idx not in selected_indexes]

            # Save the updated data in the table
            with open(data_file, 'w') as file:
                json.dump(table_data, file)

            return redirect(url_for('index'))

        else:
            new_row = {
                'forum': request.form.get('forum', ''),
                'topic': request.form.get('topic', ''),
                'torrent_size': request.form.get('torrent_size', ''),
                'replies': request.form.get('replies', ''),
                'last_post': request.form.get('last_post', ''),
                'author': 'New Author',  # You can set the author as needed
            }
            table_data.append(new_row)

            # Save the updated data in the table
            with open(data_file, 'w') as file:
                json.dump(table_data, file)

            return redirect(url_for('index'))  # Redirect per evitare invii multipli al ricaricare la pagina
    
    return render_template('table.html', table_data=table_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm trying to fix this by adding a condition to the code that checks if the row has been deleted before saving it to the JSON file. The condition is as follows:

```
if idx not in selected_indexes:
    table_data[idx] = new_row
```

This condition should ensure that only rows that have not been deleted are saved in the JSON file.

I also tried using the filter() method to remove the deleted rows from the data list before saving it to the JSON file. The code is as follows:

```
table_data = list(filter(lambda row: idx not in selected_indexes, table_data))

with open(data_file, 'w') as file:
    json.dump(table_data, file)
```

However, this code doesn't work because the filter() method doesn't modify the original list. Create a new list with the rows that haven't been deleted, but don't modify the original list.

**Table.html** code is [THIS](https://pastebin.com/raw/fM47uUub)

Comment: what does your debugger tell you the values of `selected_indexes` are?  Note that `global table_data` should be the first thing you do in `index()` otherwise you risk a problem when you do `table_data.append(new_row)`